# Custom Link related issue

Tags: custom-link

We have custom links on our Opportunity object which basically store the paths to our network folders which hold our deal related documents.

Suddenly these stopped working. I think 2-3 weeks back. Upon clicking the link, We get a blank page in a new tab.
Note that the affected users as well as the admin team have access to the network folders.

Is there anything which I'm missing here?
Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Please find the details below:

**Custom Link Details:**

Display type: Detail page link
Encoding: Unicode(UTF-8)
Behaviour: Open in a new indow
URL: file://foldername/type/{!Opportunity.RelatedFile_Name__c}

**Blank Page source:**

[image]

Any tips/help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
Saif.